# How to generate direct download link for google drive link by file id

Tags: php

I want to generate google drive direct download link without opening web page.

I have found 1 site which do same thing but I did not find how he is doing.

below is the site which generates direct download link without opening google drive page.

https://links-safety.com/download.php?id=0B475ByfcR9n4a1JMVEZxQno2Tmc

`0B475ByfcR9n4a1JMVEZxQno2Tmc` is google file and replace with any file.

can anyone tell me how can I do that?I want to make same page like above site.

I tried this url but its not working. instead of starting download it opens page.

Please guide me to do this on wordpress source code

Comment: Please before asking a question, read [mcve]

Comment: please show what have you tried (use the "edit" button to insert the corresponding code in your question). Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it.

`https://drive.google.com/u/3/uc?id=<your ID here>&export=download`

just replace  with you file id

NOTE:
not related but helpful tip
To get you file ID

1. click the file on google drive
2. then find 3 dots on right most part of window
3. select Open in new window option
4. that will open a new window with link like `https://drive.google.com/file/d/<Your file ID>/view`